# function blocking when dynamically load .so libraries

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I'm trying to dynamically load shared libraries in Linux using dlopen() command.
I encounter the following problem:
when I load just my .so then it works fine but when my .so needs to load another so(e.g: pthread) - it block forever on the dlopen() line.

my platform is: Linux, compiler: GCC

Comment: Can you show a small test that reproduces this problem?

Comment: it's little bit difficult to add a small test... just create a "hello world" Dynamic library and link it with pthread. in your main executable use dlopen("/tmp/libproblematicSo.so"); and the process will block on this function.

Comment: Without a test case, all I can say is: works fine for me.

Comment: the problem seems to occur only when using .gdb, when i execute the process manually i see no problem (no blocking), possible WA for this problem is to define LD_PRELOAD manually in the gdb env.